# Vagrant, VirtualBox - Adapter not Found?

Tags: port, virtualbox, vagrant, forwarding

Getting the following log dump when typing in 'vagrant up'. Have tried both without any messing on VirtualBox, and also with manually adding a port forwarding rule (host IP 127.0.0.1, host port 2222, guest port 22).

```
"Bringing machine 'polecat' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[polecat] Setting the name of the VM...
[polecat] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[polecat] Creating shared folders metadata...
[polecat] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[polecat] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[polecat] Forwarding ports...
[polecat] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
The adapter to attach a forwarded port to was not found. Please
verify that the given adapter is setup on the machine as a NAT
interface.

Host port: 2222
Guest port: 22
Adapter: 1"
```

Can anyone explain please what on earth I have to do to solve this? Googling sadly hasn't proved useful and the other users on my project seem to have just had this work automatically!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with VirtualBox 4.2.0. After researching for a while I upgraded VirtualBox to version 4.2.10. That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it worked after upgrading Vbox!

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, so what you're trying to do is forwarding port's if you want to do it automaticly you will have to turn on the NAT service to let other software forward ports but to do that you need to get root and ssh access to you'r bt hh2, you can do it by using this website PsiDOC.com. But if you don't want to do all this stuff you can just port forward on your router and user bridge adapter on your VirtualBox but remember that HH2 always creats seperate ips even for virtual machines. If you have any troubles with port forwarding you can use DMZ function http://scr.hu/165/l26k8