# VBoxManage.exe: error: Shared folder named '/vagrant' already exists

Tags: vagrant

Love vagrant on OSX - just trying on windows 7, but I get this error:

VBoxManage.exe: error: Shared folder named '/vagrant' already exists

Can't find any reference to it in google searches. It seems like some default shared folder is being created - to be honest I don't need a shared folder, but can't immediately work out how to disable it.

I'm using vagrant 1.2.7

Anyone else had this? Any ideas how to fix?

p.s. crossposting here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2199 am I a bad person?

Comment: `/vagrant` is shared automatically. Are you redundantly to sharing it or something?

Comment: Past your `Vagrantfile`, also try upgrade to latest 1.3.1. The project directory (where Vagrantfile resides) will by default be mounted as `/vagrant` via `vboxsf`.

Comment: Thanks Terry Wang.  I've upgraded to 1.3.1 - here is my Vagrantfile - it's just the default generated one: https://gist.github.com/tansaku/5a01c6909045003a81d4 - I destroyed it and created a new one - now I have upgraded to this error :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857766/vagrant-virtualbox-adapter-not-found hmm, time to upgrade virtualbox ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use most up-to-date version of each software(Vagrant and VirtualBox). I had some similar problem; I got them solved after upgrading my VirtualBox. I think this may help someone.